# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} nx_n.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $$x_2 \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right), x_{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin x_n(n \ge 2).$$ Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} nx_n.$

Note that $$x_{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin x_n\le \sin x_n\le x_n,$$ and $$|x_{n+1}|=\left|\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin x_n\right|\le 1,$$ it follows that $\{x_n\}$ converges. Therefore, we can readily obtain $x_n \to 0$.

As for the limit wanted, we can consider apply **Stolz theorem**. But it's too complicated.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Observe that the range of the sine function is $[0,1] \in [0,\frac\pi2]$, and the factor $1-\frac1n \in (0,1)$, so $x_n$ decreases strictly to some number between $0$ and $1$.  But this limit can't be positive, as you can apply the same process to get a smaller number.

Comment: I wonder if there's an easy closed form expression.  I tried with Python: `def x(n): return (1-1/n)*math.sin(x(n-1)) if n >= 3 else 0.5` and `n*x(n)` for $n = 100,500$ and $995$.  I got `0.9064076753543608`, `0.9054104297085305` and `0.9052871869587333` respectively.

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會 Your argument doesn't make sense. "You can apply the same process to get a smaller number" doesn't mean the limit is $0$. However, it is clear that $ x_n < \frac{1}{n-1}$ for $n \geq 3$. which shows that $x_n \to 0.$

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會. In the same spirit, using $x_2=\frac \pi 2$, compute $n^2 x_n$,It is a straight  line with a slope equal to $0.90406$ $(\sigma=0.00030)$. This linear behaviour is observed for several $x_2$.

Comment: Can we prove at least that the limit $\lim n x_n$ exist?

Comment: The existence of the limit is obvious, hopes for a closed form are... erm... *very* optimistic, so I'm not sure what this question is about.

Comment: Something to do with Contraction Mapping/ Banach Fixed-point theorem? Also note that $\lim_{n \to \infty}nx_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}(n-1)x_n,$ the latter being the limit of the nicer-looking sequence $\left(x_2,\ \sin x_2,\ 2\sin\left(\frac12 \sin x_2\right),\ 3 \sin\left( \frac23 \sin\left(\frac12 \sin x_2\right) \right), 4\sin\left(\frac34\sin\left( \frac23 \sin\left(\frac12 \sin x_2\right)\right) \right), ... \right).$

Answer (score 5):

**Work in progress**. We can conclude that $(nx_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ [converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) ...

---

Using induction we can show that $x_n \geq 0$ and, thus, $nx_n\geq0$.

Function $\sin{x}\geq0$, for $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. As a result $\sin{x_2}>0$ and
$$0\leq x_3=\frac{\sin{x_2}}{2}\leq 1<\frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow x_3\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$
And using the induction hypothesis for $x_n\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$
$$0\leq x_{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin{x_n}\leq 1<\frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow x_{n+1}\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

---

From

$$|x_{n+1}|=
\left|1-\frac{1}{n}\right||\sin{x_n}|\leq
\left|1-\frac{1}{n}\right||x_n|\leq \\
\left|1-\frac{1}{n}\right|\left|1-\frac{1}{n-1}\right||\sin{x_{n-1}}|\leq ... \\
\leq \left|1-\frac{1}{n}\right|\left|1-\frac{1}{n-1}\right|\left|1-\frac{1}{n-2}\right|...\left|1-\frac{1}{2}\right||\sin{x_2}|=\frac{|\sin{x_2}|}{n}$$
Thus
$$|(n+1)x_{n+1}|\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)|\sin{x_2}|$$
and $(nx_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.

---

Now:

$$0\leq \frac{(n+1)x_{n+1}}{nx_{n}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \frac{\sin{x_n}}{x_n} \leq 1-\frac{1}{n^2}<1$$

and $(nx_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is descending.

Comment: Well done. Further the limit must be $\le 1$.

Comment: I may have missed something, but the fact that $(nx_n)$ converges seems straightforward, since 
$$x_{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin x_n \leq \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) x_n $$

So 
$$nx_{n+1} \leq (n-1)x_n$$
 so $(nx_{n+1})$ is decreasing and positive, so it converges.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe plus bounded and positive ... 2 important details. And $nx_n$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thank you for being a great human being! Merry Christmas!

Comment: @rtybase Can you give more details ? You can prove in two ligns that $(nx_n)$ is convergent, or did I miss something ? Why do you need such a long proof ? And I don't understand your last comment... but merry christmas anyway...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe the proof is not long, just wordy and it's a work in progress. When I joined MSE, almost 9 years ago, I was "instructed" not be lazy and provide as many details as possible (different people are reading the answers). If you look at the edit history, you'll see I started with $|nx_n|$ (which converges, but actual $nx_n$ can oscillate between the positive and negative values). Then, obviously, it is important to show that $nx_n$ is positive (1st section), then decreasing (3rd section, one line).

Comment: The 2nd section is a leftover from the previous edits and another easy way to show the convergence of $x_n$ to zero.

Comment: Also, if you look at the 3rd section, we can multiply $\frac{(n+1)x_{n+1}}{nx_n}$, terms will cancel each other and the result will be $\sim \prod\limits_{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ which can be used to approximate the limit or even find it, since $\frac{\sin{x_n}}{x_n} \sim 1$ ... as I wrote, work in progress.

Comment: Re "don't understand your last comment", well ... your comment and downvote came at the same time. So, it was a thank you. Of course you can prove me wrong by downvoting me ;) ... that will teach me a lesson.